# Calling a variable stored in a literal notation object

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this literal notation object (took out the irrelevant parts):

```
var work = {
"display": function displayWork(){
    for(i in work.jobs){
        $('#workExperience').append(HTMLworkStart);

        var formattedEmployer = HTMLworkEmployer.replace('%data%', work.jobs[i].employer);
        var formattedTitle = HTMLworkTitle.replace('%data%', work.jobs[i].title);
        var formattedEmployerTitle = formattedEmployer + formattedTitle;
        var formattedWorkDates = HTMLworkDates.replace('%data%', work.jobs[i].dates);
        var formattedWorkLocation = HTMLworkLocation.replace('%data%', work.jobs[i].location);
        var formattedWorkDescription = HTMLworkDescription.replace('%data%', work.jobs[i].description);

        $('.work-entry:last').append(formattedEmployerTitle);
        $('.work-entry:last').append(formattedWorkDates);
        $('.work-entry:last').append(formattedWorkLocation);
        $('.work-entry:last').append(formattedWorkDescription);
    }
}
};
```

I have tried calling it with:

```
work.display.displayWork();
displayWork();
$(work.display).displayWork();
```

None of these have worked. How do I go about calling this function?

If i place the function outside of the literal notation object than I can call it just fine with:

```
displayWork();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
work.display();
```

The `work` object's `display` property refers to the function.

Because your function has been created with a function expression, the name `displayWork` is only usable from within the function, so if the function doesn't need to call itself (recursively) you could choose to omit this name and just say `display : function() { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is the following:

```
work.display();
```

since the `display` is a property of the object we could use the dot notation to access it and the `()` to evaluate the function that it points to.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is: 
`work.display();`

But the object *HTMLworkStart* could be missing if it is not in the global scope. So you should set it as argument:

```
 var work = {
    "display": function (HTMLworkStart){
    ...
    }
```

Then you have to call 
`work.display(HTMLworkStart);`